# i can't remove the index in list box

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove to selected index in my Listbox but I get an error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')

Please help me, I'm a newbie to C#.

```
public void listBoxName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBoxName.SelectedIndex;
    labelName.Text = clients[index].Name;
    labelAge.Text = clients[index].Age.ToString();
    labelPhone.Text = clients[index].Phone;
    labelAddress.Text = clients[index].Address;
}

private void buttonClearFields_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxName.Text = "";
    textBoxAge.Text = "";
    textBoxPhone.Text = "";
    textBoxAddress.Text = "";
}

private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxName.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxName.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: what is the number of the Integer "index"?

Comment: SelectedIndex is -1 if there is no currect selection

Comment: Seems that your 'clients' collection is simply empty. Before accessing a certain intex within a collection, first check whether the index exists.

Comment: You should 1) set a breakpoint in buttonRemove_Click(), 2) look at the value of listBoxName.SelectedIndex *BEFORE* you try to remove from the list.  Joel Coehoorn and  pm100 are both correct: the value is probably "-1".  *BUT YOU SHOULD LOOK* (instead of "assuming").  Your debugger is your friend.  Use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
int index = listBoxName.SelectedIndex;
if (index < 0 || index > clients.Length) return;
```

Comment: explain why its needed

Answer (score 0):

[`listBoxName.Items.RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat?view=netframework-4.6) requires the passed index to be in the range **0..(n-1)**, where **n** is the number of items currently in `listBoxName`.

It looks like in your case [`listBoxName.SelectedIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.6) returns a negative value.

It could be either because `listBoxName` is empty, or it contains items but none is selected.

**A possible fix would be:**

```cs
private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selIdx = listBoxName.SelectedIndex;
    if (selIdx < 0 || selIdx >= listBoxName.Items.Count) return;
    listBoxName.Items.RemoveAt(selIdx);
}
```